# How do I check if a point is behind another point relative to its location and course?

Tags: javascript, math, geolocation, geometry, geo

I am working on an app which highly depends on geolocation and calculations based upon it. One of the views is a list view which gives a list of moving POI's behind the users location.

```
+---------------------------+
+------  .            ------+
+-----    .            -----+
+----      .  [POI1]    ----+
+---        .     /      ---+
+--          .   /        --+
+-            . /          -+
+           [ME]            +
+-              .          -+
+--              .        --+
+---              .      ---+
+----  [POI2]      .    ----+
+-----              .  -----+
+------              .------+
+---------------------------+
/ = user course
..= perpendicular line
[POI1] = in front
[POI2] = Behind
```

So far I have worked out the following steps:

1. Get user location
2. Retrieve POI's in 5km radius
3. Filter all POI's at higher speed and same course (+/- 45 degrees of own course)

The next step is to determine which POI's are in front of the user and which are behind. The methodology I've figured is to create an infinite line (vector) perpendicular to the users course. (e.g. at a course of 45 degrees, NorthEast, the line would be NorthWest-SouthEast). I then need to figure out if the Lat-Lon of every poi is in front or behind this line in order to know whether it is in front of the user or behind.

All this is done with latitude and longitude in javascript. So I probably need a formula or function of some kind that will compare two latlng points to each other, relative to the course of the first point.

Google hasn't been very helpful so far, so I really hope someone can figure this out! In the mean time I will be in my bubble of shame for not paying enough attention in math class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a couple of very good and interesting approaches to this problem.
The most simple and effective one was to use a library for calculating a bearing between 2 LatLon points.

I used [GeoDesy's](https://github.com/chrisveness/geodesy) latlon-spherical.js and its `.bearing()` method to get the bearing from my to my POI relative to true north.

```
1. Get bearing to POI relative to true north
2. Subtract my own bearing to get bearing relative to me
3. Normalize bearing (e.g. add 360 to negative values)
4. Check if bearing is between 90 and 270 (this means going backwards)
```

In my code it looks like this:

```
function filterShipFromBehind(ship)
{
    // Get our and the ships latlon
    var shipLatLon = new LatLon(ship.location.latitude, ship.location.longitude);
    var myLatLon = new LatLon(myShip.location.latitude, myShip.location.longitude);

    // Calculate the bearing from us to the ship (relative to true north)
    var bearing = myLatLon.bearingTo(shipLatLon);

    // Calculate the relative bearing by subtracting our own bearing
    var difference = Ships.normalizeAngle(bearing - myShip.courseOverGround);

    // Finally check if the relative bearing is between 90 and 270 degrees
    // indicating it is behind us
    if(difference > 90 && difference < 270)
    {
        filterShipNearing(ship);
    }
}
```

I hope this helps the next one looking to tackle this problem!

Answer (score 2):

In the case illustrated above, first calculate the slope of the line between [ME] and [POI1]. In general, you want to calculate the slope between the user and a point they are traveling to (i.e. the slope of their course), which is in this case POI1. To do this, use point slope form to get the of the line slope, y1 - y2 = m * (x1 - x2), where [ME] has coordinates (x1,y1) and [POI1] has coordinates (x2,y2) and solve for m. Now let z = -1/m. This is the slope of the perpendicular line.

Back to point slope form, the general equation of the line perpendicular to the user and POI1 is given by y - y1 = z * (x-x1). Then do algebra to change the form of equation to y = z * x + b, for some b. After you've changed the form, plug in x2 for x. If y2 > z * x2 + b, then our inequality will use the "<" sign. Else, we use the ">" sign. WLOG, say we need to use the ">" sign. Then, for each POI with coordinates (k,j), if j > z * k + b, then the point is behind the user.

I know this isn't *particularly* clear, especially if you haven't done geometry like this in a while, so here's an example. Let [ME] have coordinates (1,1) and assume they are headed in the direction of point (3,2). Then, the slope of the perpendicular line is given by 1 - 2 = m * (1 - 3) which implies m = 1/2. So, the perpendicular line has slope z = -1/(1/2) = -2. Now the equation of the perpendicular line is given by y - 1 = -2 * (x - 1) which after solving for y gives y = -2x + 3. Observe that 2 > -2*3 + 3. So, our final inequality needs to use the "<" sign (the opposite sign). The final inequality is given by y < -2x + 3. Say we have two other POIs, POI2 with coordinates (0,0) and POI3 with coordinates (4,4). POI2 is behind [ME] since 0 < -2 * 0 + 3. POI3 is in front of [ME] since 4 < -2 * 4 + 3 is NOT satisfied (i.e. 4 < -5 is false).

Hope this helps. Also, be careful calculating m, since if x1 - x2 = 0, m will be undefined. This simply means the slope is straight up and down, so the perpendicular slope will be 0. Likewise, if m = 0, z will be straight up and down.

Comment: Thanks for your awesomely developed answer! However, my solution turned out to be a lot simpler in the end.